How to identify date format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
Here is the data test.log:
2024-08-22 13:00:02 9
2024-08-22 13:10:03 20
2024-08-22 13:20:03 20
2024-08-22 13:30:03 9
2024-08-22 13:40:03 9

Here is the test.gnuplot file :
set terminal x11 1
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set xtics rotate by 60 offset -3.8,-7.8
set bmargin 15
set format x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set ylabel "test Value (Bq/m3)"
plot  "test.log" using 1:2 title 'test measurement in Bq/m^3 every 10 minutes' with lines
pause 60

Result? :
$ gnuplot test.gnuplot
Warning: empty y range [13:13], adjusting to [12.87:13.13]


So it is basically identifying the hour 13 as data, disregarding the  %H:%M:%S.
Documentation was not useful on this as it just states that spaces are handled fine: http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node274.html
Found ugly workaround for those who might be stuck on the same problem :
Replace format 2024-08-22 13:00:02 with 2024-08-22-13:00:02 and then set the format to :
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"

Please let me know if I missed something.

Thanks to @choroba I could understand that my test.gnuplot needed to be amended to precise to gnuplot where is the data (1:3 instead of 1:2):
set terminal x11 1
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set xtics rotate by 60 offset -3.8,-7.8
set bmargin 15
set format x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set ylabel "test Value (Bq/m3)"
plot  "test.log" using 1:3 title 'test measurement in Bq/m^3 every 10 minutes' with lines
pause 60

I feel silly, I did miss something. Thanks again!
